# On Scrolling UIScrollView subview should not move when scrollView bounces

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, uiscrollview

I am using this control from github [Control Used](https://github.com/aaronpang/SecretViewer)
https://github.com/aaronpang/SecretViewer

I have added to subviews 

 1) For name

 2) and added two buttons

Basically i have added to backgroundScrollView.

[_backgroundScrollView addSubview:_segmentedButtonsView];

I have tried to decrease _backgroundScrollView content size.

When i add `UINavigationController` as root Controller and want to attach just at the top of tableView as per below pics, Bounce effect should remain as per the example.

[image]

But when i scroll subview should not move as per below pics.

[image]

**Note: I am using `Storyboard` and ios 7**

Comment: Can you attach a sample project?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should limit scrollviews' subviews to only a single "content" view, and embed the rest as this content view's subviews.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unsure of what you're trying to achieve, but I think you want the subviews to stay fixed above the scrollView?  I would try adding first to the _backgroundScrollView's superview like so:

```
[_backgroundScrollView.superview addSubview:_segmentedButtonsView];
```

If that doesn't work try adding it to the AppDelegate's window like so:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[[appDelegate window] addSubview:_segmentedButtonsView];
```

With the second option, you will have to remove the subviews manually on dismissal of your scrollView.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add this view to the UINavigationController, as Described here:

[How to put buttons over UITableView which won't scroll with table in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14689805/how-to-put-buttons-over-uitableview-which-wont-scroll-with-table-in-ios/20157473#20157473)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear. From what I understand you don't want the scrollview to scroll or bounce horizontally right ??

For ScrollView you can use `alwaysBounceVertical = YES;` for blocking the horizontal scrolling.

Also this can be scrollView inset issue which is common for iOS7 navigation controller, which you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924431/ios-7-navigationcontroller-is-setting-the-contentinset-and-contentoffset-of-m). To solve this you can try setting `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO`

Hope this helps you.