# UITableView moving down after navigate back from next page

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I have a tableview with frame size of(0, 65, 320, 503).When i navigate to another page then i come back it move down.
[image: Before navigate to another page]

[image: After navigate back from nextpage]

Comment: i added tableview storyboard itself...

Comment: I think you have given top constraints to table view from top layout guide. Try to uncheck under top bars property of view controller.

Comment: @user3823935 I have the same issue you had.  When I navigate back, the table, the table view already scrolled up.  So I don't navigate back to the original selected row.

Answer (score 3):

add the below line in your - (void)viewDidLoad method.

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

hope it will fix your issue.

Comment: Setting automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets to no would have the navigation bar covering the table view.  It didn't work for me neither.

Answer (score 2):

I hope you found a solution that worked for you.  This was happening to me when using AutoLayout and UITableViews combined with the wonderful SWRevealViewController class.  Long story short I wasted a bunch of time and eventually found this answer that worked for me:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23021157/892990

I moved my UITableView to a lower position in the view hierarchy (by putting a dummy 1pt-thick spacer UIView between it and the Top Layout Guide), and now it behaves as expected.

Comment: Thanks man! Exactly same issue I had, using SWReveal. Glad I got to this post!

Answer (score 0):

Place this code in view will appear,

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
{
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
}
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];
```

and also try removing auto layouts.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set frame of tableview in  viewWillAppear method again because some way in your code you r changing the frame so just set it in viewwillappear .

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `viewWillAppear`

```
[your_tableview removeFromSuperview];
[your_tableview setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];
your_tableview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 65, 320, 503);
[self.view addSubview:your_tableview];
```

You could also try this if you don't want to use the header section

```
your_tableview.tableHeaderView = nil;
```

Comment: i added tableview storyboard itself..your code will work fine.i want to know why this happending?

Comment: If my code solves your problem, then the cause of the issue is autolayout.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using storyboard.

1>set Navigation bar's translucent property to NO. Adjust your subviews frame again because after setting its NO ,the subview will be adjusting with some new frames.

2> In viewDidLoad set the following

self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;

3> its done.