# scrollview is not loading under the Navigation Bar in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, navigationbar

I fixed the ScrollView under the navigation bar, in storyboard I fix under the Navigation bar here x=0,y=65, in coding the Content Size for the ScrollView I fixed

```
    self.backgroundScrlView.contentSize=
CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width,self.view.bounds.size.height+350);
```

But it loading in the some other place I don't know why it loading there

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924431/ios-7-navigationcontroller-is-setting-the-contentinset-and-contentoffset-of-m try do

Comment: thank you so much i unchecked the Adjust ScrollView Insets Under the Attribute Inspector it's working..

Comment: are you using Autolayout?

Comment: No i'm not using autoLayout

Comment: plz try to do

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924431/ios-7-navigationcontroller-is-setting-the-contentinset-and-contentoffset-of-m

Answer (score 1):

Try self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO in your viewcontroller.

Note: This will not work for IOS 6.