# ScrollView issue Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have a view controller with a inside scrollview , but when I load the view controller the its `scrollview` isn't start from top but its almost at half screen , like this:

[image]

The `view controller` is in `pageviewcontroller` but I think that its not important.
I dont poste the code because I think that its not important in this case , but if its i will post it.

I tried to print the `contentOffset` but I get `(0.0, 0.0)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924431/ios-7-navigationcontroller-is-setting-the-contentinset-and-contentoffset-of-m

Comment: @gianni please try following code into `viewDidLoad` self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets=NO;

Comment: Are you giving scrollView constraints properly?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, And i fixed it by adding one **UIView** before **UIScrollView** ... Find the below image ...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add a UIView named "BgView" inside ScrollView(total scroll size) and give constraints.

[image]

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    scrollView.layoutIfNeeded()
    scrollView.contentSize = bgView.bounds.size
}
```