# When seguing from different controllers, scroll view is lower than it should be

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, segue

I have two table view controllers, and they both can segue to the same view which has a scroll view.

For some reason, for one view, the scroll view is lower than the other.

As you can see, the first one is coming from home view controller and is more lowered than the other one.

I have the frame's y position set as so:

```
_scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, navBarHeight + statusHeight, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
```

[image] [image]

Comment: doesn't clear the question.. Explain more..

Comment: I had the same issue, And i fixed it by adding one UIView before UIScrollView ... [Check Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36866127/scrollview-issue-swift/36867778#36867778)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to account for the nav bar and status bar height when setting the frame of your subview. Instead of y equal to navBarHeight + statusHeight, set y equal to 0.

If there's still a gap, also set your view controller's `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` property to false to prevent that behavior:

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

Comment: i already have that. Still no result.

Comment: @farhan Oh, I just re-read your question. The issue is that you set y to navBarHeight + statusHeight. Set it to 0. You don't have to account for the status height or nav bar height.

Comment: yes, i have it set as navBarHeight + satusHeight because i want the scrollview to be starting right at under the navbar. the second image as you can see does that fine.

Comment: @farhan Is the nav bar above your views the UINavigationController navigation bar? Or did you add it to your view otherwise?

Comment: Yes, its above my views. Im just thinking at this point ill create a new viewController. Been trying this all day.

Comment: @farhan You misunderstood my question... Are you using a UINavigationController? Also, did you set both scrollviews using the same exact frame? And is auto layout enable?

Comment: Yes i am using a UINav Controller. The view is fully created through code. but the view controller is in storyboard which is segued from another controller and has nav bar

Comment: @farhan you didn't answer all of my questions so it's hard for me to diagnose the issue, but if you post your project somewhere, I can take a look at it

Answer (score 0):

If you want the scrollview to be starting right at under the navbar,you can set y to 0,and

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your storyboard, click on your view controller. In the `Attributes inspector` **uncheck** `Adjust Scroll View Insets` and you're done.

[image: Uncheck Adjust Scroll View Insets]