# Swift ios 9: Section header change position after reload data

Tags: swift, uitableview, ios9

I have plain UITableView with many sections and rows. Sections work fine. But sometimes after reload data of table, section change position. For example it was happened when i change tabs. What could be the problem?

Image before changed tabs:

[image: Before change tab]

Image after changed tabs:

[image: After change tab]

**Update:** 
Add code below:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.dishesListTableView.reloadData()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}


func customizeCollectionView() {
    self.collectionView.delegate = self
    self.collectionView.dataSource = self
    self.collectionView.dataProviderDelegate = self.dishesListDataProvider
    self.collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    self.collectionView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast
    self.collectionView.registerClass(HPCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: HPCollectionViewCellConstants.reuseIdentifier)
}

//MARK: - UITableViewDelegate
func customziseDishesListTableView(){
    self.dishesListTableView.delegate = self
    self.dishesListTableView.dataSource = self

    self.dishesListTableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: DishesListSingleTableViewCell.nibName, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: DishesListSingleTableViewCell.nibName)
    self.dishesListTableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: DishesListSinglePizzaTableViewCell.nibName, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: DishesListSinglePizzaTableViewCell.nibName)

    self.dishesListTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 123
    self.dishesListTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

    if self.dishesListDataProvider.isPizza() {
        self.dishesListTableView.separatorColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    }else{
        self.dishesListTableView.separatorColor = UIColor.expSilverColor()
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.dishesListDataProvider.countOfDishes(section)
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return self.dishesListDataProvider.countOfKitchenTypes()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if self.dishesListDataProvider.getDishItemByIndex(indexPath.section, indexDish: indexPath.row).isPizza() {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(DishesListSinglePizzaTableViewCell.nibName, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DishesListSinglePizzaTableViewCell
        cell.customizeView(self.dishesListDataProvider.getDishItemByIndex(indexPath.section, indexDish: indexPath.row), dishesListSingleTableViewCellProtocol: self, indexPath: indexPath)
        return cell
    }else{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(DishesListSingleTableViewCell.nibName, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DishesListSingleTableViewCell

        cell.customizeView(self.dishesListDataProvider.getDishItemByIndex(indexPath.section, indexDish: indexPath.row), dishesListSingleTableViewCellProtocol: self, indexPath: indexPath)
        return cell
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayFooterView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    self.collectionView.scrollToIndex(section, animated: true)
    self.collectionView.changeSelectionForCellAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forItem: section, inSection: 0))
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let sectionView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed(DishesListSectionView.nibName, owner: self, options: nil)[0] as! DishesListSectionView

    sectionView.customizeView(self.dishesListDataProvider.getKitchenItemByIndex(section).kitchenTypeTitle)

    return sectionView
}
//MARK: - UIScrollViewDelegate
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if currentSectionIndex != self.dishesListTableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows![0].section {
        currentSectionIndex = self.dishesListTableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows![0].section
        self.collectionView.scrollToIndex(currentSectionIndex, animated: true)
        self.collectionView.changeSelectionForCellAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forItem: currentSectionIndex, inSection: 0))
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know it's an old thread but uncheck the `Adjust Scroll View Insets` doesn't help. I had this problem and solved it by reload table twice.

Comment: Thank you. Double reloadData() help me.

Comment: @EduardKornev double reloadData() call is a strange solution. Does anybody know a better solution?

Comment: @RomanPodymov Below one more answer, that helped some people. You can try it.

Comment: @EduardKornev And what solution are you using now?

Comment: @RomanPodymov I used solution with double reload. Another solutions didn't help me.

Answer (score 22):

```
tableView.reloadData()
tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.endUpdates()
```

This help me out.

Double `reloadData` will cause flickering while this solution won't.

Comment: Superb answer. Thankyou

Comment: I had crash on iOS 8 and iOS 9 of calling beginUpdates/endUpdates on UITableViewAutomaticDimension section footer height.

Answer (score 3):

Calling reloadData() twice also works for me, but I would suggest calling tableView.layoutSubviews() after reloadData(), which also works for me.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the issue in estimated height for your table view cells. Due to internal optimisations system calculates the height of absent cells based on estimated height value, that's why it can position your headers on wrong calculated height (like real cells bigger or smaller than their estimated size). It usually happens when you call `reloadData()` in the middle of the list. As a proper solution you should avoid calling `reloadData()` when you want to update the content of the list with second page for example. So you should use `tableView.beginUpdates()` and 
`tableView.endUpdates()` and update items collection for table view. There is also new closure based API `performBatchUpdates` (just like it was for `UICollectionView`), but it's available from iOS 11.

Hope it may help to find proper solution for you

Comment: Changing the estimatedRowHeight of the tableview to be at least as big as the the greatest cell height, and using tableView.beginlUpdates() and tableView.endUpdates solved this problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of UI viewcontroller property. Please first select UIViewController From Storyboard , Attribute Inspector

[image]

Comment: Done as you said. Doesn't help me

Comment: Have you changed also for your master Tab Bar controller?

Comment: check this  . then there may be this problem in scroll view http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924431/ios-7-navigationcontroller-is-setting-the-contentinset-and-contentoffset-of-m

Answer (score 0):

In my project ,this error happened when i pull up `tableView` to request more data then reload the data after requesting. I need create many sections after requesting the data and it may effect the performance if i `reloadData` twice. More than, i found that if i scroll up or down the `tableView`, the position of section's headerView get right. So i fix this bug(my condition) i requesting the data by this:

```
[_tableView reloadData];
CGPoint offSetOrigin     = _tableView.contentOffset;
CGPoint offSetSecond     = CGPointMake(0, offSet.y-1);
_tableView.contentOffset = offSetSecond;
_tableView.contentOffset = offSet;
```

Answer (score 0):

The solutions here didn't fix my problem, so I'm leaving one more possible solution that helped me.

Set the [estimatedSectionHeaderHeight](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614957-estimatedsectionheaderheight), it seems that my tableView wasn't being able to calculate the initial position of my first section without it.