# when adding glyptodon view to UITableViewController , Adding with some topspace

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ipad, swift2, ios9

I am presenting UITableViewController with UINavigationController. When I am trying to add glyptodon view to TableViewController getting some topspace.

```
let reminderViewController = ListingRemindersTableTableViewController()
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: reminderViewController)animated: true, completion: nil)
self.navigationController?.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and  within "ListingRemindersTableTableViewController" after calling a service i am adding glyptodon view

```
self.view.glyptodon.show("NoData Found", withAnimation: true)
```

Please help me anyone. Advanced thank you for solution.

[image: Empty table with No Data Found label]

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue. 
Issue was the frame in glyptodonview. Replace frame with bounds in glyptodonview.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to set the `Adjust Scroll View Insets` property to false in you `UIViewController` in Interface Builder.

Look at this answer: [iOS 7 -- navigationController is setting the contentInset and ContentOffset of my UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924431/ios-7-navigationcontroller-is-setting-the-contentinset-and-contentoffset-of-m#answer-18924484)