# UIPageViewController shifting up after navigation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I am using `UIPageViewController` to show 2 tabs, they are appearing perfect when I navigate to the `PageViewController` but when I navigate to any detail view from `PageViewController` and come back then `UIPageViewController` shifts up.
This only happen when I navigate from one of a child view controller of another `PageViewController` to the current `PageViewController` otherwise no issue.

This is the first child view controller from when I am navigating to a different `PageViewController`

[image: This is the first child view controller from when I am navigating to a different <code>PageViewController</code>]

This is the actual `PageViewController` causing the problem, currently no issue navigating to this screen

[image: This is the actual <code>PageViewController</code> causing the problem, currently no issue navigating to this screen]

Now the whole view is shifted up after I came back to this screen from another screen!

[image: Now the whole view is shifted up after I came back to this screen from another screen!!]

**Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks!**

Comment: Are you using Storyboard ? If yes it might be problem of setting scroll view insets. check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/18924484/1423703

Comment: No, I am not using storyboard but generating a view programatically.
So I can't use your suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the solution by adding `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;` when navigating from a particular screen.
The issue was occurring only when I navigate from another child view controller of a page view controller.

Answer (score 0):

[link](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/zwslideviewcontroller)  use this, it works perfect

Comment: Sorry, can't change the current implementation to a different one.Thanks